# JavaFX: prevent right mouse clicks to expand/collapse the TitledPane

Tags: popup, javafx, right-mouse-button

i added a ContextMenu to Header of all TitledPanes in an Accordion. it works fine, but how to prevent right Mouse Clicks from Expading or collapsing the TitledPane?

hier is my Code where i show the ContextMenu:

```
header.setOnContextMenuRequested(new EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ContextMenuEvent event) {
                        contextMenu.show(header, Side.RIGHT, 0, 0);
                        event.consume();
                            setSelectedAccount((Element)header.getUserData());
                            selectedItem.setText(getSelectedAccount().getAttribute("MAIL"));

                        }
                    });
```

**UPDATE:**

my environment: Linux Suse 12.3, JDK 1.7.0_45, JavaFX 2.2, Compiler Compliance level 1.7.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
header.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>
    () {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            if(t.getButton().toString().equals("PRIMARY"))
            {
                System.out.println("click on left mouse click");
            }
        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: and how to prevent the right click event from expading/collapsing the Contents of the Pane?

Comment: @Rami.Q i am edited above answer..i hope this work for you :)

Comment: i tried this before, its not working as expected. first time the right mouse clicked, will expande the Pane. and if i activate the expanding again on left clicks , pane expande again. i don't think , thats this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @Rami.Q i am edited answer one more time. and this was perfectly worked try this

Comment: Anshul Parashar, thank you for you tips, but there are many "errors" in your code, first one the variable p should be final since it is out side the eventhandling, and final variable cannot be assigned. Second "error": we handle mouse events, that means, node is sure allways hovered, so your if(abc.isHover() ) statement is allways true. this means abc is allways expanded. my work around is to hide the title and make my custom TitleBar. many thanks anyway

Comment: @Rami.Q yep having some error in this. i tried but have issue nevertheless, if i found something better or correct informed you

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will work fine as per your requirement:

```
@FXML
private TitledPane abc;

@FXML
void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    if(event.getButton().toString().equals("SECONDARY"))
    {
        if(abc.isExpanded())
            abc.setExpanded(false);
        else
            abc.setExpanded(true);            
    }
}
```

Comment: this prevent ABC to be expanded on right Click, however if one of the Accordion TitledPanes is expanded, will be auto collapsed on this event.

Comment: For Every  Accordion TitledPane you have to do this task.

Comment: a slight performance improvement would be:
`event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY`

Answer (score 0):

This works in Accordion.

```
@FXML
private Accordion accordion1;

@FXML
private TitledPane pane1,pane2;

@FXML
void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        if(pane1.isExpanded())
            pane2.setExpanded(false);
        else
            pane2.setExpanded(true);            
    }
```